# I can't read a JSON with getJson

Tags: jquery, json, getjson, servlet-3.0

I know that my question has been answered many times but I still cannot figure out how to make one work for me.
I am trying 2 days now to fix my problem by reading the forum but I have probably something wrong in the basics which I cannot find and in which I will need your help.

I have a servlet that creates a JSON(at least I think so) and here is the code

```
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
        JSONObject jsonItem = new JSONObject();
        jsonItem.put("position", positions[i]);
        json.accumulate("group", jsonItem);
    }

    String output = json.toString();

    response.setContentType("application/json");    
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  
    out.print(output);
    out.flush();
```

If I run the servlet I am getting the following:

```
{
  "group": [
    {
      "position": 235
    },
    {
      "position": 61
    },
    {
      "position": 248
    },
    {
      "position": 206
    },
    {
      "position": 26
    },
    {
      "position": 329
    },
    {
      "position": 176
    },
    {
      "position": 180
    },
    {
      "position": 218
    },
    {
      "position": 83
    },
    {
      "position": 177
    },
    {
      "position": 142
    },
    {
      "position": 17
    },
    {
      "position": 249
    },
    {
      "position": 310
    },
    {
      "position": 369
    },
    {
      "position": 251
    },
    {
      "position": 256
    },
    {
      "position": 337
    },
    {
      "position": 63
    }
  ]
}
```

---

My jQuery is as following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#clickMe2").click(function(){
      alert("something2");
    $.getJSON("/RandomNumGen",function(result){
        alert("something3");
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("#myTarget").append(field + " ");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Maybe it's not the right way to read it but it never goes to the second alert "something3". So I think it never reads the JSON.
I tried many ways to read it but it seems that the problem was that never reads the JSON.

I am running the servlet on a tomcat 7.0.22 and I have the `@WebServlet("/RandomNumGen")` which I think that means that I don't need a web xml but wasn't running so I decided to create a web.xml as well.
The weird thing is that when I tried once to return something with a MIME "text/html" and getting it with normal get `$.get` it does get it and it prints `[Object object]` on the browser.

Apparently I haven't used JSON before and I might miss the basics as I run really fast through the tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jquery is wrong. You have to change your `$.each`. try this

```
$.each(result.group, function(i, field){
     $("#myTarget").append(field.position + " ");
});
```

Check this out
http://jsfiddle.net/xV2vx/

Comment: Thank you for the correction and more about introducing me jsfiddle.net! However I don't think that my wrong "each" was the reason for not running the "alert('something3')" properly ...